# I specified charset in the headers, do I need to specify it in the meta/head/html?

Tags: html, http-headers, meta-tags

I specified charset in the headers, do I need to specify  it in the meta/head/html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to. The only exception I can think of is if your document is likely to be saved to a disk for later use and expected to work. If so, then it would be a good idea to include the character encoding within the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to.  But it's polite.